# My DNN module lists content of its directory when I use jQueryUI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-5, dotnetnuke-module

In my DNN module I use jquery and jquery-ui. When I add links to jquery--ui *.js files my module starts listing content of its directory.

```
Directory Listing -- /HelpDeskDNN/DesktopModules/MyControl/

[To Parent Directory]

 Wednesday, November 10, 2010 01:19 PM        3,827 MyControl.ascx
 Wednesday, November 10, 2010 12:40 PM        6,226 MyControl.ascx.cs

Version Information: ASP.NET Development Server 10.0.0.0
```

In MyControl.ascx.cs I load jQuery with

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DotNetNuke.Framework.jQuery.RequestRegistration();
    ...
}
```

And in MyControl.ascx I include jqueryUI like this:

```
<script src="LibsJS/JqueryUI/jquery-ui-1.8.6.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="LibsJS/JqueryUI/jquery.effects.core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="LibsJS/JqueryUI/jquery.ui.widget.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="LibsJS/JqueryUI/jquery.ui.tabs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="LibsJS/jquery.cookie.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Where LibsJS folder is on the same level as DNN DesktopModules folder.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is to check the module definition of your module, and make sure you have provided correct folder and ascx file selected over there.

You can go to module definitions from Host > Module Definitions
just click on edit to edit the module definition and make sure you have at least a single control added in the module definition that is not having any key specified and it is of type view.

I hope this will help you